# Catching exceptions in Java thrown from DLLs through JNI

Tags: exception, dll, java-native-interface

I am calling DLLs through JNI from Java class and I want to catch exceptions in Java class and handle accordingly which are thrown by DLLs. Can you please help me with sample example how to handle these.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Throw the appropriate Java exception class, or one of your own construction, where appropriate via `ThrowNew`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5234

```
{
......
//Somewhere in my JNI/native code, its time to throw an exception
//Pass my JNIEnv variable & my message
throwBasicException( env, "Oh Nos, I should put my details here" );
 .....
}

void throwBasicException( JNIEnv * env, std::string message )
{
    jclass exceptionClass = env->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Exception");
    jstring javaMessage = env->NewStringUTF( message.c_str() );
    env->ThrowNew(env, exceptionClass, javaMessage);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(javaMessagE);
}
```